# Как поменять местами элементы в стеке в C#?

Tags: c#, стек

Как поменять местами элементы в стеке в C#? Надо ли для этого релизовывать свой стек? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если два верхних элемента, то `pop x; pop y; push x; push y;`. Если не верхних, перекладывайте элементы во вспомогательный стек, пока нужные элементы не станут верхними.

Comment: это если два последних элемента, а если, например, сотый и тысячный?

Comment: Если элементы не идут подряд, то же самое с перекладыванием во вспомогательный стек. Перекладываете до тысячного, сотый запоминаете в дополнительной переменной, назад вместо тысячного кладёте сотый, а тысячный запоминаете вместо него.

Comment: Если вам нужно переставлять сотый и тысячный переложить -- то вы используете структуру данных (стек) не по назначению. Возьмите более подходящую. И вообще, какова практическая ценность подобной задачи?

Comment: точно ничего оптимальнее нету? может можно как-то пронумеровать элементы в стеке, чтобы через индексацию их менять?

Comment: Это уже не чистый стек будет, а какой-то гибрид.

Comment: в задаче эта структура данных именуется стеком, хотя я не думаю, что это обязательно может быть только встроенный шарповский стек, можно и что-то подобное свое написать

Comment: может вариант с Push и Pop тоже ничего, но возможно придется не один раз перебрать дважды сто тысяч элементов, не знаю, насколько это быстро будет

Comment: Если задача не одноразовая - возможно стоит написать свой стек, за основу можно взять [оригинальный](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs) и выставить у него наружу индексатор

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно перекладывать элементы не подряд и с произвольными индексами, делаем так:

```
int smallerIdx = Math.Min(i, j);
int largerIdx = Math.Max(i, j);
Stack<T> aux = new Stack<T>(largerIdx);
T tmp = default;
for (int k = 0; k <= largerIdx; k++)
{
    T curr = stack.Pop();
    aux.Push(curr);
    if (k == smallerIdx)
        tmp = curr;
}
stack.Push(tmp);
tmp = aux.Pop();
for (int k = largerIdx - 1; k >= 0; k--)
{
    T curr = aux.Pop();
    if (k == smallerIdx)
        curr = tmp;
    stack.Push(curr);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что такой подход жутко неэффективен. Если вам нужны такие операции (доступ по индексу) в вашей программе, то стек, скорее всего, неподходящая структура данных. Но с академическими целями так делать можно.

Comment: а какая структура данных тогда подходит? точно не массив, так как количество элементов может увеличиваться, но что тогда?

Comment: @Дарья List<T> используют в общих случаях

Comment: @Дарья: Перед тем, как выбирать структуру данных, вы должны понять, какие операции вы собираетесь выполнять, и насколько часто. Без этого выбрать невозможно.

Comment: list это хорошо, но мне надо удалять последний элемент, что нельзя с делать в листе

Comment: мне нужно и Push, и Pop, и новый метод Swap

Comment: @Дарья: В `List<T>` вполне можно удалять последний элемент.

Comment: если RemoveAt(последний индекс), то как-то тоже не очень эффетивно

Comment: @Дарья: Почему неэффективно?

Answer (score 2):

Если такая задача у вас не единичная — предлагаю реализовать собственный стек с открытым индексатором или методом для перестановки элементов.
Исходный код стандартного стека лежит [здесь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs), возьмите его и добавьте в него следующий метод:

```
public void Swap(int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{
    // Проверки параметров на допустимость
    ...
    T temp = _array[firstIndex];
    _array[firstIndex] = _array[secondIndex];
    _array[secondIndex] = temp;
}
```